# How to deploy a ERC-20 token for public trading after writing the .sol code?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, erc-20, contract-deployment

Say we've created a new ERC-20 token with the ticker symbol BVB, and finished writing the code for the contract as a .sol file. Does that .sol file have to be uploaded to some website online like Github, and then how do we deploy the BVB token contract so that the token is now buyable and sellable on the Ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your smart contracts using http://remix.ethereum.org/ to the ethereum blockchain,

- Install MetaMask
- Select desired network ( Mainnet, Kovan, Ropsten, Rinkeby, Goerli etc )
- Connect MetaMask with the Remix editor
- Compile your Smart Contract code
- and Deploy

Comment: ok thanks, didn't know MetaMask was involved. What for though? does deploying a new token involve gas? If so is it alot of gas? Could you edit your answer with more details about the "Compile" and "Deploy" steps? What do you mean by Compile and Deploy? What to click, what processes are actually initiated?